# How to migrate DLL from .Net Framework to .Net Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

I have a solution containing more .Net Framework projects. I need to move the current application libraries to .Net Standard in order to be used by other projects.

I know I can do this by removing the current projects and recreating them with .Net Standard, then adding each class and dependency back to them, until I finish. This approach is acceptable in my case as the application is not huge, but I wonder if there is an easier way than this.

I was looking for something like the way that Target framework is usually changed for projects:

[image]

But there is no entry for .Net Standard here.

Comment: If your project file is still in the pre-2017 format, [this](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) may help. Once your project is in the new format, changing the target(s) is easy. (Of course, you may then need some more work to patch up references and change actually incompatible code, if there is any.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, how do I know if the project file is in the pre-2017 format? The projects are old, indeed, but I opened them with VS2017.

Comment: @meJustAndrew then they aren't. It would be better to create a new .NET Standard 2.0 project and copy the files over. You have a bigger problem though - .NET 3.5 is essentially 2.0 plus libraries. There was a *breaking change* going to .NET 4 8 years ago. Before moving to Standard, try changing the target to 4.6+, better yet *4.7.2*. You may find compilation errors that need fixing *before* you try to move to NS 2.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the problem will be just at copying and pasting a lot of classes and reinstalling nuget packages in a lot of projects. It's doable, but it will take plenty of time. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @meJustAndrew you should first target **4.7.2** though. That's the first .NET Runtime version that actually supports .NET Standard 2.0. The 4.6.x versions target Standard 1.x and the attempt to use compatibility packages to add NS 2.0 support didn't really work

Comment: @meJustAndrew those NuGet packages may no longer be needed, or they may not even support 4+, much less NS 2.0. Take things one step at a time. Add the 4.7.2 SDK and make sure the project compiles for 4.7.2 first. The new csproj format doesn't require adding *all* packages anyway, you only need to add the root dependency in each case. MSBbuild/VS will detect and download dependencies automatically

Comment: @meJustAndrew: VS 2017 supports the old format, but it will not convert to the new one. Merely opening a project file in 2017 will not trigger a conversion. (This is unlike how project files generally worked in older versions, and is mostly a good thing, but the completely lack of even a manual conversion is why third-party tools exist.) Whether or not it's faster than starting from scratch will vary based on just how complicated your code base is.

Comment: @meJustAndrew NuGet packages is the reason you shouldn't use 4.6.2 to test the code btw. The compatibility packages add a *LOT* of dependencies that aren't needed and leave behind a lot of binding redirects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to manually edit the `.csproj` file, modifying the [TargetFrameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) tag:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But personally in cases like that I am creating empty project then do replacing of old csproj file.

Comment: I have seen the possibility to modify the project target framework [here](https://codehollow.com/2017/05/port-net-framework-net-standard/) but it didn't sound so simple, and I got some errors with it which made me consider remaking the projects. On the other side, there are plenty of projects with more classes and nuget packages which makes this approach hard also...

Comment: @meJustAndrew it's not so simple. This setting can be used only in the new `csproj` format. Only new .NET Core and Standard projects in VS 2017 use that format. You have to modify the file by hand in all other projects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos with that said, it gets more and more clear that I will be making these changes manually. I will start with targeting for 4.7.2, as you said. Thanks once again! I am still open to hear other alternatives if there is any.

Comment: @meJustAndrew I feel your pain, I am in progress of upgrading asp.net to aspnetcore and I did create new empty aspnetcore and slowly moved everything there.